# auto resize with css

Tags: css, image, html, resize

I have the following problem:

I have an image that goes through slides, I need that it is always resized to the size of the window and the monitor, I thought I'd use:

```
min-height: 100%; 
min-width: 1024px; 
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
```

But does not solve my problem in the above image shows my current problem, I have a header DIV and a FOOTER DIV which is superimposed the image and the image is getting underneath the two divs eating pieces of it, how do I fix this?

An image to demo:

[image: http://i46.tinypic.com/prqdl.jpg]

Comment: try position:relative (or absolute) and setting z-index:1000 for example (in your css of course)

Comment: Added the css example for you

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    min-height: 100%; 
    min-width: 1024px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 

    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

That will make sure the image appears above everything

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="image">
    <img src="image_path">
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

If that is your source, your css should look like this.

```
#header,#footer{
height:150px; // You set the number
width:100%;
}

#image{ /* The code you were using */
     min-height: 100%; 
     min-width: 1024px; 
     width: 100%; 
     height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolás! This code resolve 50% of my problem, now, the img is cuting only in the footer, an image to demo: http://i50.tinypic.com/2im0t8h.jpg

Comment: You have to add the same rules to everything that should be above. z-index places things in different "levels" if one could say so. So if you want the footer and header to be above the image just give the image a smaller z-index than the header and footer.

Comment: Actually, what I need is that the image is always set at the ends of the header and footer, regardless of the display or resolution, as it is a photo site ... the problem is not only the image of 'eat' a piece

Comment: I understand now, I added a little example to see if it helps you

Comment: Very thanks to help me! But is not work, the div image not resize according the footer, its my div footer:


#footer-container {height:85px;display:block;background:#0a0a0a url(images/bg-footer.png) repeat-x left top;clear:both;position:fixed;bottom:0px;z-index:100;width:100%;}
#footer {display:block;margin:0 auto;width:950px;overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Could you please post your html and your css? Thanks

Comment: My url: thiagosolano * com * br/index2.php/

Comment: On line 469 of your style.css you have position:fixed. The footer is fixed to that place. If you remove the line, it will go straight to the bottom of the image. But when the image changes it will pop right up until the new image appears. In that case you have to set a fixed height to your "bg" div.

Comment: Yes, I tried some tests... So, how I can do to img and bg resize automatic? My head will go explode... rs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12171/discussion-between-nicolas-torres-and-gtokai)